# Aramaic Lord's Prayer (Mt. 6:9-15) transcribed into IPA for pronunciation?

Tags: matthew, aramaic, lords-prayer, resource-request

I am looking for a transcription of the Aramaic *Lord's Prayer* ([*Abun d'Bashmaya*](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/images/7/78/Abun.pdf), [Mt. 6:9-15](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=6&l=9-15#x)) into [International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)](https://www.paulmeier.com/ipacharts/), for aiding correct pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for

/ɑbun dəbaʃmaja/

/nitqaddaʃ ʃməχɑ/

/tita mɑləkuːtɑχ/

/ihwe nɑʃe bəʃmɑjɑ kɑn baɑʁʁɑ/

/hɑwwob lɑxmo desojnɑn jomɑnɑ/

/uʃboq lɑn lɑxmo χobɑjnɑ/

/dɑfɑn lɑn χwobɑjnɑ/

/oχ dijnɑ zbel /

/lɑ pɑʁna min bejʃɑ/

/metoq dehwe mɑlkutɑ uhojbɑ uʃbooχɑ leolam olmijn/

/ɑmen/

Comment: Yes. How did you generate it? Please provide some reference(s).

Comment: I am a linguist and I have trained in my career with knowledge of articulatory phonetics